# Sending model class with Boolean values to retrofit endpoint that doesn't sometimes accept that boolean value

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I want to ignore a boolean value when sending request all other data types work fine but boolean is set to false by default and is sent even when endpoint doesn't accept it ..
NOTE: I don't want to use transient in GSON because other endpoints accept that boolean value

```
public class UserModel implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("agePrivate")
@Expose
private  boolean agePrivate;

@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;

@SerializedName("_id")
@Expose
private String _id;

@SerializedName("user_id")
@Expose
private String user_id;

@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;

@SerializedName("phone")
@Expose
private String phone;

@SerializedName("birthdayDate")
@Expose
private String birthdayDate;

@SerializedName("job")
@Expose
private String job;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;
@SerializedName("location")
@Expose
private LocationModel location;
private String freind_status;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, `boolean` primitive type's default value is always `false`, You should replace `boolean` by it's equivalent object type which is `Boolean` and it's default value is `null` and null will be ignored by Gson.

So replace:

```java
@SerializedName("agePrivate")
@Expose
private  boolean agePrivate;
```

with

```java
@SerializedName("agePrivate")
@Expose
private Boolean agePrivate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to different approach like sending the data value by value by extracting values from the object.

```
@GET("/endpoint")
Call<List<model>>    getdata(@Field("location") String var, ....);
```

Call that on creating object of call like this

```
Call<List<model>> call = interface.getdata(obj.getLocation(),...);
```

Then it will be easy to do this.